# Emacs compilation mode won't see bash alias

Tags: emacs, emacs23

Emacs M-x compile does not see any aliases set in .bashrc. If I use M-x shell then type the alias, it is fine. I tried sourcing .bashrc from /etc/profile, from ~/.profile, ~/bash_env, anything I can think of to no avail.

I am on Emacs 23 and Ubuntu 11. I start emacs using /usr/bin/emacs %F, from a desktop button.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Emacs inherits its environment from the parent process. How are you invoking Emacs - from the command line, or some other way?

What happens if you:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> compile <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-a</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> bash -i -c **your_alias** <kbd>RET</kbd>

Invoking bash as an interactive shell (-i option) should read your .bashrc aliases.

Edit: I think both <kbd>M-x</kbd> shell-command and <kbd>M-x</kbd> compile execute commands in an inferior shell via call-process. Try the following in your .emacs (or just evaluate):

```el
(setq shell-file-name "bash")
(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")
```

I notice that after evaluation of the above, .bashrc aliases are picked up for use by both <kbd>M-x</kbd> shell-command and <kbd>M-x</kbd> compile, i.e

<kbd>M-x</kbd> compile <kbd>RET</kbd> **your_alias** <kbd>RET</kbd>

should then work.

My environment: Emacs 24.1 (pretest rc1), OSX 10.7.3

Comment: A warning: for me this has the side effect of making autocomplete.el run extremely slowly. Presumably it is repeatedly creating bash shells somewhere and running my entire .bashrc every time.

I might try writing a wrapper around compile that temporarily changes shell-command-switch to "-ic".

Comment: (about `shell-command-switch "-ic"`) No, it DOESN'T work with `shell-command`. Ubuntu 16.04, emacs 24.5. There errors printed out: "bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device.
bash: no job control in this shell". If I remove `-i` option from `shell-command-switch`, `.bashrc` with aliases defined isn't loaded. See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3447. Advice "Emacs inherits its environment from the parent process" seemed nice and worked with `export`s BUT aliases in subshells doesn't work! See http://superuser.com/questions/319538

Answer (score 9):

Keith Flower's answer works but can result in some slowdowns due to .bashrc being unnecessarily loaded in other places (presumably many many times, my computer is not exactly under-powered but emacs was almost unusable when trying to use autocomplete.el).

An alternative way is to locally modify `shell-command-switch` only for the functions where it is needed. This can be done using emacs' "advice" feature to create a wrapper around those functions. Here's an example that modifies `compile`:

```
;; Define + active modification to compile that locally sets
;; shell-command-switch to "-ic".
(defadvice compile (around use-bashrc activate)
  "Load .bashrc in any calls to bash (e.g. so we can use aliases)"
  (let ((shell-command-switch "-ic"))
    ad-do-it))
```

You need to write similar "advice" for each function that you want to use .bashrc (e.g. I also needed to define the same advice for `recompile`), just copy the above and replace `compile` in the above with another function name.

Answer (score 2):

You may like emac's bash-completion :

https://github.com/szermatt/emacs-bash-completion

You'll be able to use tab completion of your aliases in the compilation minibuffer and in shell-mode.

Enjoy !

(they speak about it here [Bash autocompletion in Emacs shell-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163591/bash-autocompletion-in-emacs-shell-mode) )

Answer (score 1):

I think compilation commands are not interpreted through a shell: they are juste exec'ed by emacs (which means aliases, shell functions and other shell-specific things are not taken into account).

Try to wrap you compilation command into a shell-script which would source the correct environment.

You can do this either with a full-fledged shell-script in the form

```sh
#!/bin/bash
source "~/.bashrc"
my_command
```

or directly in emacs with a compilation command of the form

`bash -c "source ~/.bashrc; my_command"`

Comment: Francesco, I tried the bash -c thing on the compile command,  and same result: bash: [my alias]: command not found

Comment: No need for the bash -c part; just add "source /home/$USERNAME/.bashrc &&" prior to any further commands in the compile-command variable. I'm using this myself and it works quite well.

Comment: I have an alias named run_csv. I did as you asked, source /home/[ME]/.bashrc && run_csv. The result is /bin/bash: run_csv: command not found

Comment: have you tried writing a shell-script ? In my case (which is slightly more complicated than yours), it works pretty well.

Comment: When I place those shell scripts to a well known directory, and add their path to $PATH, then I'll have similar problem, \C-x\c will not see them. But maybe fixing a PATH issue is easier than fixing an alias issue. So I might give this a try, if I see no other viable answers here. It is quite annoying Emacs still has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

See [Is there a way to get my emacs to recognize my bash aliases and custom functions when I run a shell command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224909) for a fix which doesn't run all your .bashrc and doesn't create these error messages:

> bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
>   bash: no job control in this shell