# How to get auto-complete in Scala REPL launched from ensime?

Tags: scala, emacs, sbt, ensime

I can get auto-complete in an Ensime buffer containing Scala code but not in the Scala REPL launched from ensime. I wish to have auto-complete work in the Scala REPL launched from ensime. How can I fix this? I am using the following:

1. Scala 2.9.1
2. sbt 0.13.5
3. scala-mode2 from elpa

I also have this for the contents of `plugins.sbt:`

```
addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "ensime-sbt-cmd" % "0.1.2")
```

Now, the only other thing I have noticed is that in my `.ensime` file, it appears to be compiling for scala version 2.10. Note, that I can get auto-complete if I open scala from a terminal.

In summary, how can I get auto-complete from the scala REPL launched from ensime?

Comment: Do the last two comments in the comments section of this article help ? http://ensime.blogspot.in/2010/08/pencils-down.html

Comment: And this: http://jawher.net/2011/01/17/scala-development-environment-emacs-sbt-ensime/

Comment: Not really... Apparently this is not a feature of Ensime, I asked on their github.

Comment: Is auto-complete working in terminal mode? My scala REPL auto-completes fine. You may want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163591/bash-autocompletion-in-emacs-shell-mode

Answer (score 0):

I am going to repost CodeKingPlusPlus's own comment on this question:

> Apparently this is not a feature of Ensime, I asked on their github.